# База данных MySQL и Django

Tags: python, django

Как правильно соединить базу данных MySQL и Django? При выходе я получаю подобный набор символов, а иногда ошибку utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte. В базе данных стоит кодировка utf8_general_ci везде, где только можно. В чём может быть проблема?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Проверьте кодировку самой БД https://gahcep.github.io/blog/2013/01/05/mysql-utf8/

Comment: Проделал то, что описано в статье, не помогло.